# How can I generate an EOF (or an ASCII 0) in a visual studio debug console?

Tags: visual-studio, eof, getchar

I have a console-mode program running on Windows.   The program calls `getchar()` in a loop unitl either an `EOF` or a `0` is returned.   I'd like to enter one of the following as a test vector while running the debugger:

"`abc\0`"  or  "`abc\EOF`

I can't seem to consistently generate either.  I tried the suggestion [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1793616/10396) by typing <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>".    That returns `97,98,99,26` to my program, and then hangs on the next `getchar()` call.

Entering <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> doesn't hlep either, `getchar` returns a 4 for the control char, then a newline char, and then it duplicates the line I just entered on the console.  It's like VS is using the control characters as editing characters.

EDIT:
Here is a stripped down version of the code I am using.  I see identical behavior in the debug console and in a command window.

```
#define MAXSZ 4096
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   short int data[MAXSZ]={0}, i=0; 
   char c;
   do {
      if (i==MAXSZ) break;
      c = getchar();
      if (c!=EOF) data[i]=c;
   } while (data[i++]!=0);
   for (i=0;data[i]&&i<MAXSZ;i++)
      putchar(data[i]);
}
```

How do I enter an EOF or an ASCII 0 in <strike>the Visual Studio debug</strike> a Windows console?

Comment: A binary zero can be entered by typing Ctrl+@ (hold down Ctrl, press 2 key), echos as ^@ on the screen.  You have to press Enter next since getchar() uses buffering.  Or use _getch() from `<conio.h>` to input unbuffered text.

Comment: that's the solution I ended up using for my test.  I'd still like to know if it's possible to reliably generate an EOF which gets processed before the Enter key.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
<Enter><Ctrl-Z><Enter>.
```

Comment: sorry, the 2nd example was supposed to read CTRL-D.  Fixed and expanded the info.

Comment: That's odd. Could you post the code you're using to check for EOF?

Answer (score 0):

@Hans Passant solution works for me - should also work for OP.
  1 To generate an ASCII 0, type (Ctrl+@ ) or (Ctrl+2 )
  2 To generate an EOF, type (Ctrl+Z Enter), but the input buffer needs to be empty. So this is typically *after* an (Enter), thus (Enter Ctrl+Z Enter).

But OP code has problems.

```
char c; // should be int ch
do {
   ...
   c = getchar();
   if (c!=EOF) data[i]=c;
} while (...);
```

In OP code, if the character ASCII 255 occurs , it gets assigned to a `char` (-1) which compares to EOF.  Instead use `int ch`.

```
   if (c!=EOF) data[i]=c;
   // should be
   if (c==EOF) break;
   data[i]=c;
```

This prevents the code from looping forever or erring once an EOF occurs.

---

To enter ASCII 255
(Alt key down, num pad 2, num pad 5, num pad 5, Alt key up)