# Having troubles with EOF on Windows 7

Tags: c, eof

I'm currently learning C with K&R and I'm having a hard time sending EOF simulation through cmd. I was trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> which did nothing.

In some cases <kbd>Enter</kbd> is doing the work and in other cases nothing does it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Ctrl-z is right for Windows, however iirc the effect is not immediate. You still have to hit Enter afterward.

Comment: I have tried them both, didn't work.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1793631/866193) to a similar question says that Ctrl-Z + Enter is the way to go.

Comment: Hi Sam thanks but I was saying that I have tried Ctrl+Z -> Enter and it didn't work. In the case I mentioned when Enter only did the job, it was nothing but Enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on Windows, the situation is that you basically have to do the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> at the beginning of a line -- i.e., you have to have hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, then do the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then (depending on how the input is being read) possibly <kbd>enter</kbd> again.

You can also use <kbd>F6</kbd> to signal the end of the input. At least in most cases, this will work even when/if it does *not* immediately follow an <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Unfortunately, Windows provides enough different ways and modes to read input, that it's a little hard to state a whole lot with absolute certainty unless we know the compiler you're using (or, more specifically, the standard library) as well as the exact code you've written. Under normal circumstances, just hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> should *not* be detected as end of file, but your code could be treating an empty line as the end of input.

Comment: I know it's not perfect but it should work, or at least print 'All good baby...'
http://pastebin.com/MGgGhHiP

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows 7 console window, I had success pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. <kbd>F6</kbd> produces the end-of-file ^Z symbol at the command prompt.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> causes the console window to quit execution, not only the user program.