# Using EOF and getchar() for character counting in C

Tags: c, windows, eof, getchar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't getchar() recognise return as EOF in windows console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793616/why-doesnt-getchar-recognise-return-as-eof-in-windows-console)

I'm new in C and trying to figure out how EOF and getChar() works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

int number = 0;
while(getchar() != EOF)
     number++;

printf("%d", number);
}
```

When I type some random characters, the program doesn't do anything, I think that it never gets out of that while loop. Why is that? I'm using CodeBlocks on Windows 7.

Comment: EOF is the marker for End Of File. Type CTRL+Z or change the condition to exit the loop with a character on the keyboard.

Comment: Because EOF can not be typed by a keyboard. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you aren't sending an `EOF` character.  "EOF" stands for "end-of-file"; console input (known as "standard input") is a special case of a file.  But in order to denote that this special file has ended, you need to send a special signal.  You can get this effect on Windows by pressing Ctrl+Z (followed by Enter, for some reason).