# what is EOF key in C++

Tags: c++, io

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate. I am new to C++. Following is my exercise for switch statement.

```
void GradeBook::inputGrades()
{
    int grade;

    cout << "Enter Grade: " << endl;

    while((grade=cin.get()) != EOF)
    {
       switch(grade)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                aCount++;
                break;

            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                bCount++;
                break;

            case 'C':
            case'c':
                cCount++;
                break;

            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                dCount++;
                break;

            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                fCount++;
                break;

           case '\n':
           case ' ':
           case '\t':
               break;

            default:
                cout << "Incorrect data. Re Enter" << endl;
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

I run this inside netbeans, and I pressed all the combinations ctrl+c , ctrl+z, ctrl+d but it is not ending!! Why is that? Have I done something wrong? Please help!!

Comment: I think your question isn't really about EOF, but here's about it : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file

Comment: Control+Z or F6. Normally needs to be entered on a line by itself, so basically enter followed by Control+Z or F6.

Comment: hmm..Still not working.. Are you sure it is working in netbeans? Or else, isn't it better to change the argument test to -1 ? So, when the user enter -1, it will break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [EOF character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793616/why-doesnt-getchar-recognise-return-as-eof-in-windows-console/1793631#1793631) is Ctrl+Z followed by a newline character on Windows platforms.

Presumably that will be the same for the console within Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

cin.get() is pretty low level. The code should use a higher-level interface. It's supposed to read a character at a time, so write it that way:

```
char grade;
while (cin >> grade)
```

The stream extractor will fail at end of file, and that will make the while loop terminate.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The problem here is about how to "type" the end of the input.

Comment: It's a helpful answer, but it's the wrong answer.  I'm not sure if I should upvote or downvote.