# When the input will stop?

Tags: c++, string, loops, io, stream

Hi guys i have the following question:

`string s;`

```
std::cout << "give me a string" << std::endl;  
while (std::cin >> s){
    std::cout << "give me a string" << std::endl;
}
cin.clear();
```

if **s** was an integer then i know that if i typed a **char** then the **while** would break. If it was an **integer** and typed a **double** the same would happened. But what about **strings** ?? Somewhere I read that in windows (as I am writting at netbeans in windows) you have to press ctrl+z and then it stops as it is taken as a false string. But when i do this , the process freezes and nothing happens.

Comment: Shouldn't double enter stop this?

Comment: it won't stop this. If i type `ctrl + d` it actually stops !! thx for answer btw !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the EOF signal, which in Netbeans is <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>.

However, hitting Enter twice will result in the condition of your loop to resolve in false, causing the loop to stop. That's excpected: [How is "std::cin>>value" evaluated in a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395801/how-is-stdcinvalue-evaluated-in-a-while-loop)

If that doesn't work, use <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> and a newline character, which is the EOF signal in Windows, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11938387/2411320). <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> is for Linux though, but it works in your case.

The EOF signal closes the input stream, thus breaking the loop.

---

Moreover, in Netbeans (if the above doesn't work) it seems that you need to [run your application from the command prompt](https://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic33863.html) to achieve this. Another attempt would be to "press <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> after pressing Enter", as stated [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/90193/).

Comment: Not on Linux. Pressing `Ctrl + D` there does finish the stream and hence the program, though.

Comment: I tried double enter on VS 2012 and it does not work (tested in default console). Precisely, pressing enter does not enter into a loop brackets.

Comment: thanks for the answer , actually it won't stop , as it changes 2 lines and after that it waits for an input. If I type something it will accept it. @jdehesa is so right , it actually worked!! thx

Comment: @gsamaras Yes, I mean, I can't really say for sure why two enters do not work on Linux (I guess it does on Windows? I haven't checked), or whether it should, I just tested the program and noted it didn't. Maybe it's a Windows-specific thing?

Answer (score 1):

The loop will stop when the input stream is closed.

If you run the program from a shell, then the input stream may be open indefinitely. Exactly how you would close the stream in a terminal, depends on what terminal you are using.

In UNIX, the stream is closed when you send empty input. `ctrl + d` is the standard key combination for sending (flushing) the input to the stream (`^d` is the ASCII control code EOT, end of transmission). Pressing enter also sends the input, but it also inserts the end of line character, so it is not possible to use it to send empty input.

`ctrl + z` is similar in windows, but it has [different behaviour (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character):

> The EOT character in Unix is different from the Control-Z in DOS. The DOS Control-Z byte is actually sent and/or placed in files to indicate where the text ends. In contrast the Control-D causes the Unix terminal driver to signal the EOF condition, which is not a character, while the byte has no special meaning if actually read or written from a file or terminal.

Comment: As i stated before in a comment `ctrl + z` it does not stops the process , so `ctrl + d` will do the job. Thx for the answer !