# end of input getline

Tags: c++, input, getline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t getchar() recognise return as EOF in windows console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793616/why-doesnt-getchar-recognise-return-as-eof-in-windows-console)

I have a simple problem... Lets say I want to read lines from standart input as long as there is something, but I dont know how many lines it will be. For example I am doing school work and input is

```
a
ababa
bb
cc
ba
bb
ca
cb
```

I dont know exactly how many lines it will be, so I tried

```
string *line = new string[100];
    int counter = 0;
   while(getline(cin,line[counter]))
   {
    counter++;
   }
```

But it doesn't work... thanks for help.

Comment: Well for example i enter "aa", enter, "bb", enter and now i dont enter anything and just press enter but nothing happen.. and i need to end reading from input after last value was entered.

Answer (score 4):

If you want input to end on an empty line then you have to test for it. For instance.

```
string *line = new string[100];
int counter = 0;
while (getline(cin, line[counter]) && line[counter].size() > 0)
{
    counter++;
}
```

Congrats for using `getline()` correctly BTW. Unlike some of the answers you've been given.

Comment: if your counter getts bigger than 100 this will lead to seq faul. right?

Comment: @dreamcrash, Yes. Better code would be to use `std::vector<std::string>` and `push_back()` to add a line to the vector. But I like to introduce one new thing at a time.

Comment: ``!line[counter].empty()`` would be much faster than ``line[counter].size() > 0``

Comment: @hinafu How much money would you be willing to bet on that claim? :)

Comment: I don't know, the money I get when I get TLE instead of AC in an online judge, which is zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of lines with something like:

```
   string *line = new string[SIZE];
   int lines = 0;

    while(lines < SIZE && getline(cin, line[lines]) && line[lines].size() > 0) 
   {
        cout << input_line << endl;
        lines++;
   }
```

Don't forget to check if you are not adding  more **lines than the size** that string line can handle, otherwise you can get Segmentation Fault.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest line counter I can think of would be something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

unsigned int count = 0;

for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    ++count;
}

std::cout << "We read " << count << " lines.\n";
```

Test:

```sh
echo -e "Hello\nWorld\n" | ./prog
```

If you want to discount empty lines, say `if (!line.empty()) { ++count; }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the end of file marker for this. Its usage is like this.

```
std::ifstream read ("file.txt") ;

while(!read.eof())
{
  //do all the work
}
```

This function returns true if end of file has been reached. So it would continue until you encounter that.

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comments as well, the method `eof` could be dangerous and not provide the desired result. So there is no guarentee that it would run in every case.
You can have a look here about when this might happen.

[Reading from text file until EOF repeats last line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647/reading-from-text-file-until-eof-repeats-last-line)

Comment: That's an extremely dangerous suggestion that usually leads to terrible code. It's nearly impossible to use `eof()` in a sane or correct fashion.

Comment: Absolutely right. As OP has school work and input format is given, i thought it would most probably run fine.

Comment: *Teaching* this sort of terrible idea to innocents is even worse -- that's why almost every SO post pertaining to C++ I/O is *wrong* in the same way, and people with "years of C++ experience" don't get this stuff right, either. The best thing we can do is never even mention that `eof()` exists to anyone but the most advanced programmers.

Comment: What! How did this get three up-votes? -1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int cont = 0;
string s;
while(cin >> s) { //while(getline(cin,s)) if needed
  if(s.empty()) break;
  ++cont;
}
```