# Is printf supposed to print out a 'long' value?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t getchar() recognise return as EOF in windows console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793616/why-doesnt-getchar-recognise-return-as-eof-in-windows-console)

I'm trying to print out the value in the variable 'nc' in the next program:

```
int main()

{ 
 long nc;
 nc = 0;

 while (getchar() != EOF)
 ++nc;
 printf("%ld\n", nc); 
}
```

Please tell me why is it not printing?

Comment: Did you end the input with Ctrl+D?

Comment: Are you sending EOF? It works for me.

Comment: In order for the loop to exit, try typing `Ctrl+D`.

Comment: "Not printing"? I just tried running your code and it works as expected. What are you using as input for your program?

Comment: @user1959174: In that case, why do you expect your program to print anything, if you never end the `while` loop?

Comment: hi @AndreyT it was my bad, i didn't realize that until you guys mention my problem here. I only started learning C 2 days ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have brackets in your while loop (this is why not using brackets leads to error prone software). Therefore, the value is getting incremented, but not printing.

Try:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
    long nc;
    nc = 0;

    while (getchar() != EOF)
    { // ADD THIS
        ++nc;
        printf("%ld\n", nc); 
    } // AND THIS
}
```

otherwise, your code is essentially doing:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
    long nc;
    nc = 0;

    while (getchar() != EOF)
    {
        ++nc; // ENDLESSLY ADDING
    }
    printf("%ld\n", nc); // NEVER REACHED DUE TO WHILE LOOP.
}
```

Comment: too bad there is no feature that you can add certain people that help you in the past to future question :) @Inisheer

Comment: @user1959174 Maybe, but I could certainly see that getting out of hand as well :P  .

Comment: hah yes i know, this is probably the reason they didnt do it in the first place. I'm sure they though of that @Inisheer . tell me buddy, I just recently started to learn programming and took C as the first language cause people recomanded me that if I want to learn Objective -C, it will be good o have a solid understanding of C. I started couple of days ago with the book "the c programming language" (k&r), do you think its a good book for programming beginners?

Comment: @user1959174 See here for good recommendations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop will continue to loop until you end the input using Control-D on Unix or Control-Z, Return on Windows. It will do this without printing anything because you did not use braces around the ++nc and printf.

You may also have problems with printf if you did not `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of your program. If the compiler does not know that printf is a varargs function, it will not format the argument list correctly when calling it.

Answer (score 3):

after entering some inputs like

`1`
`2` `4`
u must type `ctrl + D` since its the EOF `ASCII` equivalent.

Else modify the progeam and put

> while(getchar()!='\r')               (until you hit `Enter`)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean? It works:

```
./a.out 
asdfsdfasdfasdfasddddddddddddddddddddddd
41

echo "Try to count this" | ./a.out 
18
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to stop reading characters from stdin by stopping the while loop of getchar

and then you will see the nc value printed

To do

`EOF` = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (for Linux)

`EOF` = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (for Windows)