# how putchar works with while loop?

Tags: c

I am new to c programming, so hope you guys can help me out with such questions.

1. I thought `putchar()` only print 1 char each time, while when I enter several char like 'hello' it print 'hello' before allow me to enter a next input? I thought that it should print only 'h' and then allow me to enter other input because `getchar()` only return one character each time.

2. how to make the loop stops? I know EOF has value of -1, but when I enter -1, the loop still runs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{   

    int c = getchar();

    while(c != EOF){
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }

}
```

Comment: Regarding #1, you're looking for a `kbhit`type functionality. that isn't how portable `stdin` works. [see this question for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed). Regarding #2, [see this question's various answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793616/why-doesnt-getchar-recognise-return-as-eof-on-the-console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first `getchar()` has completed reading one character, the next `getchar();` is inside the `while()` loop, so as per the logic, it will keep reading the input one-by-one, until in encounters `EOF`.

Following the same logic, `putchar(c);` is under the `while` loop, so it will print all the characters [one character per loop basis] read by `getchar()` and stored in `c`.

In linux, `EOF` is produced by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. When waiting for input, if you press this key combination, the terminal driver will transform this to `EOF` and `while` loop will break.

I'm not very sure about windows, but the key combination should be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Note: even if it seems entering `-1` should work in accordance with `EOF`, actually it won't. `getchar()` cannot read `-1` all at a time. It will be read as `-` and `1`, in two consecutive iterations. Also worthy to mention, a *character* `1` is not equal to an *integer* `1`. A *character* `1`, once read, will be encoded accordingly [mostly ASCII] and the corresponding value will be stored.

Comment: so the loop ignores the expression: c = getchar(). But why c only returns one character in the input, putchar() still can print all the input?

Answer (score 0):

1. getchar() gets the input from the console.  In a while loop, it will read all the characters from the input including the return key.
2. -1 is "-1".  It's not a value but just another combination of characters.  EOF occurs when there is no more char in the buffer. i.e. when you press Enter (or Ctrl-Z or Ctrl-D depending on your OS)

Comment: are you sure pressing `ENTER` sends `EOF`, not a `\n`?

Comment: @Sourav.  You are right.  Enter will send the input to the program but won't stop the loop.  You need a if (c == '\n') break; or something.