# ending program using '\0' in c programming- while loop

Tags: c, while-loop

I have trouble finishing a while loop using `'\0'` in c programming language, the c code is the following

```
#include<stdio.h>

char r;

int main()
{
    do 
    {
        scanf("%c", &r );
        printf("%c", r);
    }
    while (r!='\0');

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that the program never finishes at the final character of typed string line, the while loop is always in waiting mode because of the `scanf` and never go to `return 0`. I do not know why this happen.

The output of this program is like this:

```
1234
2345
4556
7788
2345, 4556, 7788
```

Those are numbers I typed, but the program never finish (never go to `return 0`), I want to print just one string and I want the program ends.

Comment: You can't enter zero. Change it to %d and `int` or compare  the char value with '0'

Comment: how can i finish a string? how can i know the end of a string? and then print the typed string? is it possible to use "/0" to know the end of the string?

Comment: You do not have any strings there. So there is nothing to terminate with zero

Comment: the strings are typed by the user, for example a 1234, 2345, etc... but the program never finishes, i want the user type one string and then the program prints the string after that i want the program end (while loop finish)

Comment: i am using "\0" the null character in order to end the string

Comment: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) putchar (c);`

Comment: But you do not have a string there. What string? String is a char table. You only have char

Comment: yes, i made a mistake, the user typed several characters and it supposed the program finishes  when find the /0 null character, thanks for the suggestion above

Comment: How did you type the null character?

Comment: @PeterJ_01 `'\0'` can be enter.  Various keyboards allow it or a file can be piped into `stdout`

Comment: first, check if the input value is printable, before trying to print it.  (the `isprint()` function from `ctype.h`)  Second, a 0x00 ('\0') byte can be entered via <alt-000>, however, much easier to just check for the terminating '\n' (newline) character.

Comment: suggest checking the returned value (not the parameter values) from the call to `scanf()`.  In the current scenario, the returned value will be 1 unless an error occurs or the user enters (depending on the OS) <ctrl-d>  or <ctrl-z>

Comment: @chux I don't think, he asked about entering the char using the alphanumeric values.

Answer (score 2):

Typical user input is a *line*, a sequence of characters up to and including a final `'\n'`.

As a part of user input, `'\0'` is just another character.  It is often difficult to key in.  Some keyboards allow it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>@</kbd> or other ways [@user3629249](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48615135/ending-program-using-0-in-c-programming-while-loop/48615753#comment84228373_48615135)

Very rarely is a *string* (a sequence of characters up to and including a final `'\0'`) used on input.

To handle user input, a simply approach is to use `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input.  That input will be saved as a *string* by `fgets(buf)` by appending a *null character* `'\0'` to the characters read: all saved in `buf`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char buf[100];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    puts("End-of-file or error encountered");
  } else {
    // maybe lop off the potential trailing \n from buf
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
    printf("User input was <%s>\n", buf);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

To end user input, the usual approach is to signal the "end-of-file", see [recognise return as EOF on the console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1793616/2410359)

If code *must* use `scanf();`, check the return value to detect end-of-file or input error.  [@user3629249](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48615135/ending-program-using-0-in-c-programming-while-loop/48615753#comment84228402_48615135)

```
if (scanf("%c", &r ) != 1) {
  puts("End-of-file or error encountered");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer back

Comment: @OmarElioTorresCastillo: I see it's been a while since you last asked a question here. Accepting an answer is still the proper thing to do (and merely commenting "thank you" still is not).